# Why getting property could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value and must be a non-null value of type 'System.Boolean'

Tags: entity-framework

I got the following SP and when running the application it gives the error :

> The 'HaveReaction' property on 'spFADMGetHours_Result' could not be
>   set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a
>   non-null value of type 'System.Boolean'

Well, the `HaveReaction` is a bit and when I add the stored procedure to the context and look at the property it is of type Boolean so it recognized it well.  I tried to delete everything about this SP from the context and reinsert it no luck.  I don't understand why I'm getting this error since the field is declared as bit and EF imports it as Boolean so what is wrong and where and why ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFADMGetHours]
@Patients varchar(max),
@DateToProcess varchar(10)

AS BEGIN DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

-- The IF is for entity framework integration
if @Patients is null and @DateToProcess is null
begin
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS datetime) AS SOMEDATE, CAST(NULL AS time) as SOMEHOUR, 0 AS TotalToTake, 0 AS TotalTakenOrIncident, CAST(0 AS bit) AS HaveReaction
end
else
    begin
        SET @sql = 'SOME QUERY'
        exec(@sql)
    end
END
```

Comment: What about `SOME QUERY`? Could problem be there? It seems, that the first `if` is correct.

Comment: The SOME QUERY is a query which returns the same thing as the if it was big so I didn't think it would be relevant to show it.  All fields in SOME QUERY are of same data type and of course this SOME QUERY isn't visible to EF at all since the if is needed for EF to know how to construct the COMPLEX TYPE.

Comment: We changed 0 AS TotalToTake for CAS(0 AS decimal(18,2)) AS TotalToTake and we are now facing the same problem by EF.  It reports the error :

System.InvalidOperationException: The ''TotalToTake'' property on ''spFADMGetDays_Result'' could not be set to a ''System.Int32'' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type ''System.Decimal''.

However when I inspect the property it is of type decimal so both side EF and SQL are decimal.  Why it wants to set it to System.Int32 when both sides are decimal ?

Comment: Finally the work around we found is to replicate the whole SOME QUERY and using a WHERE that will never get any data.  This is actually working.  It seems that CASTING is something EF somewhere in the CORE doesn't understand !

Answer (score 0):

It's not a precise answer but a work around that works.

The work around we found is to replicate the whole SOME QUERY and using a WHERE that will never get any data.

That's probably because EF needs real SQL table fields to map correctly.  I may be wrong so correct me if it's the case